# SendKeys through IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, sendkeys

I'm able to SendKeys.SendWait through IIS Server Express (debugging through Visual Studio) but it doesn't work when site is hosted on IIS Server. It seems that I need to run asp.net site as Administrator but I have no idea how to do that and need some steps to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Don't forget that this will send the message to the machine that the application is running on. In this case when you try it on your local machine it sends the signal to your local machine and it all appears to work okay. When you deploy it to the server the message is sent to the server. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I expect for. I need it to have ability to control applications running on server (WMP in this case) through web form hosted on IIS Server which is accessed from intranet.